# .NET XML web service, consuming class not able to access web service class

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am creating a simple XML web service and have run into something I can't quite explain.

My web service class has the following structure :

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Xml


<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://www.mynamespace.com/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class MyWS
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloName(Byval name as String)
         return String.Concat("Hello",name)
    End Function

End Class
```

Invoking my method using the built in VS web service test harness works fine.

I created another project, in another solution, to test consuming the web service. I added a web reference to my project and set it so I could reference my web service by using "localWS". Then in the page load event of my consuming class I tried to instantiate an object of my web service:

```
Dim srv As New localWS.MyWS
```

But there was no "MyWS" type found. There is however a localWS.MyWSSoapClient class. When I use it I can invoke my web methods. My question is, why can't I create a straight up version of MyWS class? In the tutorials I'v read, and in the book I have, example consuming classes for .NET XML web services can instantiate objects of the web service class they are consuming.

As a further test I added a new web form to my web service project and from there I was able to instantiate a MyWS class.

Could anyone tell me why I can't create a MyWS object in my consuming code? Is MyWSSoapClient equivalent? Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyWS class is the server part of your client-server solution. It shouldn't be accessible by a consuming system (client). If it was, then there would have been no reason for exposing the functionality of the MyWS class as a web service.

The MyWSSoapClient class is generated from the metadata (WSDL) of your web service when you add the web reference. It is a class that your client can use for communicating with your web serivce.